# How to retrieve individual tree results? (R randomForestSRC package)

Tags: r, package, random-forest, survival-analysis

I want to extract the by tree predictions for each observation from the rfsrc object. In other words, for i trees and j observations, I want to extract an [i,j] matrix of the predictions. My goal is to calculate the prediction confidence intervals using the R code found at https://github.com/swager/randomForestCI. My analysis requires a competing risks random forest; otherwise I would have used the randomForest package which makes the by tree predictions more obvious to extract.

I appreciate any assistance.

EDIT: I am attempting to follow the procedure outlined here: http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/03/confidence-intervals-for-random-forest.html